# Можно ли как то добавить в свое приложение типовое окно для загрузки файлов?

Tags: c#, windows, wpf, winapi

Хотелось бы узнать можно ли сразу подключить типовое окно для загрузки файлов ( например такое же как используется при прикреплении документа к письму в электронной почте) или же все это нужно прописывать вручную? И каким образом это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Да, можно. В WinAPI - совершенно точно `GetOpenFileName`, в .NET - `OpenFileDialog`, судя по google.

Answer (score 5):

Вот пример из [официальной документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()
{
    DefaultExt = ".txt",
    Filter = "Текстовые документы (.txt)|*.txt",
    ValidateNames = true,
    Multiselect = false
};

bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();    
if (result == true) // явное сравнение с true нужно, потому что Nullable
{
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
    // обрабатываем
}
```

Заметьте, что вам нужен [`Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), а не [`System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Бегло посмотрел описание классов для .NET и не понял в чем между ними разница. Она есть?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: (1) по фичам есть небольшое, (2) ну и не нужно тянуть за собой зависимость от WinForms.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: Плюс можно использовать метод `ShowDialog(Window w)`.

Comment: Спасибо. Зависимости в .NET для меня неведомы...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: WinForms — это как бы более старый и ретроградский фреймворк. Если можно скомпилировать проект без него, то почему бы и нет.

Comment: @VladD ну не надо так сразу на WinForms наезжать, да старенький, зато объезженый со всех сторон и нормально работает на слабых машинах,  в отличие от WPF, которому не смотря на все достоинства ресурсов иногда таки не хватает =) У меня тут попался такой образчик из свежей поставки оборудования, Win8 на целерончике и с 2Гб ОЗУ

Comment: @VladD хотя в целом, согласен конечно, этот диалог более функционален, взять хотя бы создание массива потоков при мультиселекте файлов

Comment: @rdorn: Ой :) Целерон + W8 конечно тормоза, да. WPF очень хорош стилями, Binding'ом, layout manager'ом, наследованием DataContext'а и стилей, DynamicResource'ами, анимациями из коробки, и собственным рендерингом. Прикиньте, как на WinAPI/WinForms сваять комбобокс, элементами которого были бы какие-нибудь видеоплейеры. С дополнительными кнопками. На WPF это не проблема. Ну и с MVVM отделять контент от представления во много раз легче. (Окей, я фанат WPF и пристрастен.)

Comment: @VladD "Ой :)" вот у меня такая же реакция была, когда железо увидел, пришлось использовать как тонкий клиент, на большее не годятся. А с достоинствами WPF я ни разу не спорю =)

Comment: @rdorn: Угу, с такой аппаратурой лучше конечно WinForms. :-\